# What is the purpose of "do" tag in twig

Tags: symfony, twig

I have seen the twig documentation about `do` tag, but I don't understand its use/useful.

The [docs](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/tags/do.html) says the follow:

> The do tag works exactly like the regular variable expression ({{ ...
>   }}) just that it doesn't print anything:

and show an example:

```
{% do 1 + 2 %}
```

What to solve exactly this tag ?

Answer (score 4):

Good question! I found [a link on GitHub to when this was proposed](https://github.com/twigphp/Twig/issues/446) which might add some further info:

> Sometimes you want to do things, or call some stuff, and ignore the output. For example if you use a |shift filter to remove some data from an array, doing {{ arr|shift }} will output the removed item, which is not always desirable.
>
> Of course it's possible to do {% set null = arr|shift %}, which won't
>   output anything, but it also looks weird.

The example in the docs is poor as it explains nothing at all, as you pointed out.